# Can you propagate a bamboo plant from cuttings?

Tags: propagation, cuttings

I have 2 bamboo trees ([*Phyllostachys nigra*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllostachys_nigra)) approximately 1 meter in height each. I would like to  propagate new bamboo plants from cuttings. Is this possible?

Comment: You asked about "bamboo" but tagged it [lucky-bamboo]. Which do you mean? The ornamental plant sold in containers as "lucky bamboo" is actually an entirely unrelated plant (Dracaena). The differing answers will not be compatible. Please clarify what you are asking and 'flag' to reopen. Thanks.

Comment: Bamboo cuttings (both cases) can be kept in water for few days till new roots began to appear.. then you can transplant it to potting soil... it will surely work!

Comment: Just to add some relevant information - @jaczjill worked perfectly. I kept them in water (with very little kelp fertilizer) for three days and they started developing small roots - transplanted them to potting soil immediately and they seem very happy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bamboo cuttings (both cases) can be kept in water for a few days until new roots begin to appear. The cuttings can then be transplanted to potting soil.

Comment: where should you take the cuttings from? Old growth, new growth?

Comment: A healthy (properly grown), stem works efficiently..! However, I have never tried with new buds.

Comment: I took fresh "branches" from the plant, no thicker than 1mm.